# Detect and install framework 4.5 when program execute

Tags: c#, .net, frameworks

I have VS2013 EE WinForms application with target .net 4.5.
When I try to execute my app under Win7 without 4.5 framework installed exception window appears (0xc000007b).
What should I set in my app settings for showing a good info window with download framework option?
I don't want to publish installation file, just want exe with dll-s so publish is not my target.

Comment: What you can do is to write another application with lower version of framework to check is 4.5 version installed and starts you main app if everything is ok.

Comment: In addition to what Reniuz said: you can pack your 4.5 application **inside** your 2.0/4.0 application so you'll always deploy only one executable.

Answer (score 1):

try:

http://thecodeventures.blogspot.com/2012/12/c-how-to-check-if-specific-version-of.html

reffers to msdn

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568.aspx

```
    private static void Get45or451FromRegistry()
{
using (RegistryKey ndpKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry32).OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\NET Framework Setup\\NDP\\v4\\Full\\")) {
    int releaseKey = Convert.ToInt32(ndpKey.GetValue("Release"));
    if (true) {
        Console.WriteLine("Version: " + CheckFor45DotVersion(releaseKey));
    }
}
}
// Checking the version using >= will enable forward compatibility,  
// however you should always compile your code on newer versions of 
// the framework to ensure your app works the same. 

private static string CheckFor45DotVersion(int releaseKey){
if ((releaseKey >= 379893)) {
    return "4.5.2 or later";
}
if ((releaseKey >= 379675)) {
    return "4.5.1 or later";
}
if ((releaseKey >= 378389)) {
    return "4.5 or later";
}
// This line should never execute. A non-null release key should mean 
// that 4.5 or later is installed. 
return "No 4.5 or later version detected";
}
```

kind regards

Answer (score 0):

you can check in registry which framework is installed ? If VS version is below to 4.5 give a message window to download that version.

you can easily find out how to check VS version installed ?

here is the link http://www.mztools.com/articles/2008/MZ2008003.aspx

Comment: His application doesn't start without framework so how you thinking  app will check something?

Comment: yes, I am giving same option to check in registry using another application.